# How to change default value size parameter of the terms aggregation when multiple values in field?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

According to the Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size), the "terms" aggregation returns the top ten terms with the most documents. In my particular case, I am sending 14 required values to count on.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "respondents": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "my_field": [
                      "1",
                      "2",
                      "3",
                      "4",
                      "5",
                      "6",
                      "7",
                      "8",
                      "9",
                      "10",
                      "11",
                      "12",
                      "13",
                      "14"
                    ],
                    "size": 20 // this is not working
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But then 4 of them are not returned.
If I add the "size" property side by side with "my_field" property, then an error is returned:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[terms] query does not support [size]",
        "line": 40,
        "col": 49
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[terms] query does not support [size]",
    "line": 40,
    "col": 49
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

What should I do to be able to get all 14 required values?

Comment: try changing the size at the top of your query, the one that's set to 0, and see if that does what you want

Comment: Your query does not contain a terms aggregation. It contains filters aggregation. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: MarkWalkom size is there at the top, and I think it is not related. @YD9 you were right, it was a filters' aggregation, and I needed to add the real terms aggregation as the accepted answer does. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `term` aggregation and `filter` aggregation doesn't support `size` param as it will apply filter on aggregation query.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "respondents": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "my_field": [
                      "1",
                      "2",
                      "3",
                      "4",
                      "5",
                      "6",
                      "7",
                      "8",
                      "9",
                      "10",
                      "11",
                      "12",
                      "13",
                      "14"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "my_field",
            "size": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked as expected at first. I am only used to very simple queries. Where can I find more information on this? Documentation examples are way too basic.

Comment: You can check elastic documentation only but again they have not given example for each and all usecase so you need to do some of the R&D as well. But for above example you can find details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html#use-filters-agg-for-multiple-filters).